# suggestion about pattern match on sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have to substitute the `getzb="0" zztype="0"` with `getzb="2" zztype="1"` on the line contained `qsid="90"` or `qsid="100"` so I wrote the following `sed` command:

```
sed '/qsid="90"\|qsid="100"/s/\(getzb=\)"0" \(zztype=\)"0"'/\1"2" \2"1"/
```

It looks ugly, did any one has good tips?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sed -r '
    /\bqsid="(90|100)"/{
        s/\bgetzb="0"/getzb="2"/g;
        s/\bzztype="0"/zztype="1"/g
    }
'
```

### Sample Test

```
$ cat file
getzb="0" zztype="0" foobar
getzb="0" zztype="0" 
getzb="0" zztype="0" qsid="90" or qsid="100"

$ sed -r '
    /\bqsid="(90|100)"/{
        s/\bgetzb="0"/getzb="2"/g;
        s/\bzztype="0"/zztype="1"/g
    }
' file
getzb="0" zztype="0" foobar
getzb="0" zztype="0" 
getzb="2" zztype="1" qsid="90" or qsid="100"
```

Comment: -1 according to the question, the replacements should only be made on the lines containing `qsid="90" or qsid="100"`. Your answer: `sed -r 's/getzb="0"/getzb="2"/g; s/zztype="0"/zztype="1"/g' file` will make replacements on other lines as well.

Comment: This will change `zztype="0"` no matter `qsid="(90|100)"` holds or not, maybe {} should used around the processing part

Comment: No, you have an old version, copy/paste again. It's fixed.

Comment: Added `\b` in the command (word boundaries) for more robustness